# How to get image data in Magento 2 without HTML markup?

Tags: php, magento2

The following code gives me HTML full of spans around the image.

```
<?php

$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);

echo $productImage->toHtml();

?>
```

I would like to know how to collect the image data for images in Magento 2 so that I can put together the HTML as I want it.

The following code gives me the URL of the original image. But I want the small sized image.

```
$block->getUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product' . $_product->getImage()
```

This is what I want:

**/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.php**

```
<?php

$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

// Get front image in small size for category view

$get_main_image_url = '';
$get_main_image_width = '';
$get_main_image_height = '';
$get_main_image_alt = '';

echo '<img src="' . $get_main_image_url . '" width="' . $get_main_image_width . '" height="' . $get_main_image_height . '"' . ' alt="' . $get_main_image_alt . '">';

// Get back image in small size for category view

$get_back_image_url = '';
$get_back_image_width = '';
$get_back_image_height = '';
$get_back_image_alt = '';

echo '<img src="' . $get_back_image_url . '" width="' . $get_back_image_width . '" height="' . $get_back_image_height . '"' . ' alt="' . $get_back_image_alt . '">';

}

?>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up overriding the image PHTML file by saving a file here:

*[your_magento_installation]/app/design/frontend/[your_vendor]/[your_theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml*

You might want to copy the contents of either image.phtml or image_with_borders.phtml. This is what my file looks like:

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image */ ?>

<img
     <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCustomAttributes(); ?>
     src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageUrl(); ?>"
     width="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getResizedImageWidth(); ?>"
     height="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getResizedImageHeight(); ?>"
     alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($block->getLabel(), null, true); ?>"/>
```